# Remove group_by field from final result rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5.2.0.

I have a `City` model in which `id is a Primary key` and `name` represents name of city.

I am using group_by to achieve something like this:

Expected Output:

```
{10571=>"Μorocco Town", 17741=> "S-HERTOGENBOSCH"}
```

I am trying something like this:

```
City.all.select('name', 'id').group_by(&:id)
```

The result I am getting is:

```
10571=>[#<City id: 10571, name: "Μorocco Town">], 17741=>[#<City id: 17741, name: "S-HERTOGENBOSCH">]}
```

The key part is correct. 
I need to `get rid of the id field` coming in the hash value and also, a single hash value instead of an array with name as key.

Any suggestions?

Using group_by is not mandatory. Any other inbuilt functions will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pluck is your friend...

```
City.pluck(:id, :name).to_h
```

Comment: This is very clean and short